# How can I change/update a search result on wordpress for astra theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This one I cannot figure out. I cannot figure out where and what should I do to change excerption under my search results. This screenshot are results that I get after clicking on search button when my input was empty and what you see are some leftovers from testing mostly. I have access the search from a category and not a page itself. What I do get are results from pages but none of exceptions is for my likings.

[Results from search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4nar.png)

I have tried fixing it with google search console, changing meta description whit plugin Yoast SEO but apart from that I have ran out of ideas.